# Microsoft Teams bot messaging extension: invoke/selectItem not working as expected

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

So we are currently building a bot / app for Microsoft Teams and have based our query/search messaging extension on this code sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search/bots/teamsMessagingExtensionsSearchBot.js

This works fine on the desktop client of Teams when we post a **NEW** conversation (selectItem is invoked correctly). When using this for a reply however, after selecting the entry, the reply area just closes and does not render any card... Also, on Teams mobile (latest Android version), selectItem is never called. There is a button to expand the card but it's not working..

I could live with mobile not working as expected, though having it this broken in replies is making the selectItem basically useless..

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue. We already have a bug on this which is being tracked. Thanks!!

Comment: This is now also happening for the new "New conversation" button, which basically makes this functionality completly useless for our app. Any idea about this?

Comment: I can confirm that it is happening to me too. Is it a bug of MS Teams or is there something to be done specifically in returning the compose extension?

Comment: It's a bug in Teams, and one that is still not fixed...